# Laravel query builder/Eloquent mass update use data from current query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'd like make something like this `Pseudocode`

```
UPDATE `table` SET `path`=REPLACE('pathpath','other',`path`) WHERE `ready_to_publish`=1
```

But I'd like to use Eloquent/Query builder. I know that exists `DB::raw` and I can set directly but the application must support many RDBMS types and use query builder is comfortable.

I know that I can make it in 2 queries

1 Get all id,path where ready_to_publish is 1 replace in PHP
2. Build update query with all data in chain.

My question is, does it is possible in one query like in pure SQL.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
Table::where('ready_to_publish',1)->update(['pathpath',$newpath]);
```

And you need to define `pathpath` as fillable in model like,

```
protected $fillable = ['pathpath'];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I can solve my problem by this.

For example my laravel code

`\DB::table('files')->where('directory','layout')->update(['directory',str_replace('layout','layout.my',$directory)]);`
and in this case I'd like to in `$directory` place should be current `directory` column value.

Comment: @jaroApp Then, sorry I haven't understand about your problem